# Maths mode with chemmacros

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros, chemformula

I am a beginner with `chemmacros` and I have a problem during the compilation when I want to use greek letters inside the `\ch{}` command. Here is an example:

```
\ch{\Delta E=h.\nu}
```

A solution is to write this :

```
\ch{$\Delta E=h.\nu$}
```

However, I know that there is another solution as the initial command was already compiled on another computer. And as I have a 10,000 lines file, I cannot fix everything by hand...

Here is the package I loaded :

```
 \usepackage{upgreek}
 \usepackage{chemmacros}
 \usepackage{textgreek} 
 \chemsetup{greek=textgreek}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
```

I am using MacTeX2016 with LaTeX v3.62 and the lastest chemmacros version.
Any idea? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: That looks more like physics, not chemistry. Are you sure, the commands of `chemformula` are fitting your needs?

Comment: Reason i am asking: There is a difference between a variable (typeset italic) and a chemical element (typeset upright).

Answer (score 7):

`\ch{\Delta E=h.\nu}` should *never* have worked (I surely never intended it to). Also it doesn't make sense: `$\Delta E=h\nu$` is a *mathematical* formula and not a chemical one. If you *need* math in a chemical formula `chemformula` offers to surround the entry with `$…$` as you've already discovered.

Using `\ch{$\Delta E=h.\nu$}` is still wrong – not only semantically: the spacing is also wrong. Use `\ch` for chemical formulae and equations and math mode for math expressions and equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

wrong: \ch{$\Delta E=h.\nu$} \par
correct: $\Delta E=h\cdot\nu$\par
correct: $\Delta E=h\nu$

\bigskip

correct: \ch{H2SO4} \par
wrong: $H_2SO_4$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`\Delta E=h.\nu` is invalid syntax for the `chemmacros` `\ch` environment,  but will compile in the `\ce` environment from `mhchem`.

Inclusion of `upgreek` will clear italicization from nu.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}

{a.} \ce{\Delta E=h.\nu}\\

{b.} $\Delta E=h.\nu$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It will compile but I wouldn't call it valid syntax for mhchem, either!  Also the spacing is wrong